# 2 XORed AES-ECB ciphertexts, zero key and piece of plaintext

Tags: aes, xor, ecb

1. I have $C_1 \oplus C_2$ where $C_1$ = $AES128_k(P_1)$ and $C_2$ = $AES128_k(P_2)$.
2. I know the *`k`*, it is 0 (i.e. 16 bytes of zeros).
3. I know the piece of $P_1$ (7 bytes).

How to restore the plaintexts ($P_1$, $P_2$), knowing all this?

Comment: This is essentially one-time-pad where plaintext is $C_1$ transformed from $P_1$ using $\operatorname{AES-128}_k$ with pad being $C_2$ transformed from $P_2$. I think there's no hope.

Comment: Well, There is no magic here. AES is 16-byte permutation, so you still need 9-byte = 72-bit unknown part of $P_1$. You need to search for this. This is a lot of space for a probably HW,CTF so there must be some means to reduce this. Once you set up the search of the remaining part, encrypt $P_1$, get $C_1$, find $C_2$ and decrypt $C_2$ to get a probable $P_2$. Now what? You need some means to determine that $P_2$ is the target like containing some word from a language. You may get many possible $P_2$s to determine. Hey, what is the known part of $P_1$? It may lead you continue by default...